# Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:116) error before running

Tags: java, spring, jpa

This is repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BooksForHealthPolicyRepository extends JpaRepository<BooksForHealthPolicy, BooksForHealthPolicyId>{

    public List<BooksForHealthPolicy> findByCollectionDateGreaterThanEqualAndCollectionDateLessThanEqualAndProductCodeAndProductSubCodeAndBs1100Not(int collectionStartDate,int collectionEndDate, int productCode, int productSubCode,char bs1100);
}
```

and in entity, field is:

```
"   @Column(name = "BS1100", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private char bs1100;"
```

When i ran the service, it cant even start and it gave the error:

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:116) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.doFindAllNodes(JoinProcessor.java:120)
```

so, that is why i think it is about "not in" keyword. Can it be? but at my local, it works.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13638 known issue for version 5.4.4. It is fixed in 5.4.9

Comment: Ah, the good old `StackOverflowError`... it's like a secret achievement!

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `BooksForHealthPolicyId` in `JpaRepository<BooksForHealthPolicy, BooksForHealthPolicyId>`
you are supposed to give the Wrapper class type of the id if i'm not wrong.

Comment: Which one, i could not get it